# Envío de email desde Android Studio con JavaMail

Tags: email, javamail

soy novata y estoy intentando enviar un mail desde Android Studio con javamail. He revisado todos los tutoriales habidos y por haber y no hay manera.

Tengo instaladas las librerías activation.jar, additionnal.jar, mail.jar
tengo dados los permisos en el manifest, he obtenido la contraseña para aplicaciones de la cuenta de gmail y aunque no da error no manda el email.

El código del método que debería enviar:

```
    private void enviarConGMail(String destinatario, String asunto, String cuerpo) {

    //La dirección de correo de envío
    String remitente = "proyecto@gmail.com";
    //La clave de aplicación obtenida según se explica en este artículo:
    String claveemail = "****************";

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  //El servidor SMTP de Google
            props.put("mail.smtp.user", remitente);
            props.put("mail.smtp.clave", claveemail);    //La clave de la cuenta
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");    //Usar autenticación mediante usuario y clave
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //Para conectar de manera segura al servidor SMTP
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //El puerto SMTP seguro de Google

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            try {
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(remitente));
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(destinatario));   //Se podrían añadir varios de la misma manera
                message.setSubject(asunto);
                message.setText(cuerpo);
                Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
                transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", remitente, claveemail);
                transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
                transport.close();
            }
            catch (MessagingException me) {
                me.printStackTrace();   //Si se produce un error
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Agradecería cualquier orientación que me pudieseis dar o si me podéis recomendar algún tutorial o similar, ya no se que probar.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante agregar el error que se produce para saber como solucionar el problema, revisa [ask]. Que se imprime aquí ?: me.printStackTrace();   //Si se produce un error

Comment: No se produce error alguno, si sigo el código paso a paso me da la sensación de que cuando llega al Thread salta y no ejecuta lo que se encuentra en el interior pero error no da.

Comment: Peroooooo ¿por qué usas Java Mail? En Android puedes enviar un correo mediante un `Intent` sin más ... ¿Por qué a la gente le gusta complicarse la vida? [Mira aquí el ejemplo de Intent llamado `composeEmail()`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common?hl=es-419#Email).

Comment: Hasta donde he visto mediante Intents salta la aplicación de mensajería para que sea el usuario quién envíe el mail, yo necesito que el mail se envíe de manera automática al pulsar un botón y sin interacción del usuario.

Comment: @Criba Pueden ser varias cosas, permisos e incluso la configuración que defines, por esto es necesario verificar cual es el error, imprime en el LogCat el mensaje de esta forma, dentro del catch agrega Log.e("ERROR", "Error : " + me.getMessage());

Comment: Esto es contradictorio: *yo necesito que el mail se envíe de manera automática al pulsar un botón y sin interacción del usuario*, el hecho de **pulsar un botón** es una interacción del usuario, simplemente escucha los clicks de ese botón y desde ahí lanza el `Intent` que envía el correo.

Comment: Y, si no recuerdo mal, poniendo algo como `intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));` no te mostrará varias aplicaciones para enviar el mensaje, sino que lo enviará con la app de email por defecto que tenga el usuario... Otra posibilidad sería enviarlo desde el servidor, en caso de que tu app esté conectada a un servidor remoto.

Comment: O, si todos los posibles emisores son clientes de Gmail, como parece ser, entonces una mejor opción sería usar [la API de Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending).

Answer (score 1):

Estos son los pasos para hacer funcionar el JavaMail en Android actualizado. *Septiembre/2023*:

1. Implementa las dependencias en el archivo **build.gradle**.

   ```
   android {
       packagingOptions {
           resources {
               excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
               excludes += '/META-INF/{NOTICE.md,LICENSE.md}'
           }
       }
   }

   dependencies {
       implementation "com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.7"
   }
   ```
2. Agrega los permisos necesarios en tu archivo **AndroidManifest.xml**:

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
3. El siguiente código debe estar en un proceso asíncrono (AsynTask o Thread):

   ```
   final String email = "correo_a_enviar@example.com";
   final String subject = "asunto";
   final String message = "contenido";

   // Configurar propiedades del servidor SMTP
   Properties props = new Properties();
       props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
       props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
       props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.example.com"); // Reemplaza con tu servidor SMTP
       props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); // Puerto SMTP

   // Configurar la sesión de JavaMail
   Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
       @Override
       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
           return new PasswordAuthentication("tu_correo@example.com", "tu_contraseña_de_aplicacion");
       }
   });

   try {
       // Crear un objeto MimeMessage
       MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);

       // Establecer dirección de correo electrónico del remitente
       mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("tu_correo@example.com"));

       // Establecer dirección de correo electrónico del destinatario
       mimeMessage.setRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));

       // Establecer el asunto del correo
       mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);

       // Establecer el contenido del correo
       mimeMessage.setText(message);

       // Enviar el correo
       Transport.send(mimeMessage);

   } catch (MessagingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
4. Asegúrate de que la contraseña sea de aplicación:

- Para obtener la contraseña de aplicación debes acceder a "Gestionar tu
  cuenta de Google" > "Seguridad" > "Verificación en dos pasos".
- Luego debes activar la "Verificación en dos pasos" como se indica.
- Una vez esté activada debes ir a contraseñas de aplicación
  [image: captura de pantalla]
- Después, poner el nombre de la app y clic en el botón "Crear".
  [image: captura de pantalla 2]
- Finalmente te dan la contraseña que debes usar en la app.